# Chart.js Grouped Bar Chart Onclick Event

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have started implementing grouped bar chart using chart.js. One group has two bars - first evaluation and second evaluation. While clicking on the bars (each) it must directed to a detailed page with certain parameters (parameter values are different for each bar).

- In this case I am not able to distinguish X-Y axis values and different bars(1st or 2nd).
- On click event is triggered even outside the bar(including on the bar)

I expect your assistance to solve the above mentioned issue

[This is the format of implemented chart.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99uZD.png)

```
 success: function (chData) {
                var aData = chData;
                if (aData.monthText != 0) {
                    $('#lblnodata').html(' ');
                    var FirstEvaluationData = [];
                    var SecondEvaluationData = [];
                    var FirstOrder = [];
                    var SecondOrder = [];

                    for (i = 0; i < aData.firstMonthEvaluation.length; i++) {

                        FirstEvaluationData.push(aData.firstMonthEvaluation[i].evaluationScore);
                        FirstOrder.push(aData.firstMonthEvaluation[i].evaluationId);
                    }

                    for (i = 0; i < aData.secondMonthEvaluation.length; i++) {

                        SecondEvaluationData.push(aData.secondMonthEvaluation[i].evaluationScore);
                        SecondOrder.push(aData.secondMonthEvaluation[i].evaluationId);
                    }



                    var pointBackgroundColors = [];
                    var point2BackgroundColors = [];
                    var ctx = $("#myChart").get(0).getContext("2d");
                    var myNewMonthChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                        type: 'bar',
                        responsive: true,
                        animation: true,
                        showDatapoints: true,
                        data: {
                            labels: aData.monthText,
                            datasets: [
                                {

                                    datalabels: {
                                        color: 'black',
                                        font: {
                                            weight: 'bold'
                                        }
                                    },
                                    label: "1stEvaluation",
                                    data: FirstEvaluationData,
                                    order: FirstOrder,
                                  
                                    //backgroundColor: "#3cba9f",
                                    backgroundColor: pointBackgroundColors,
                                    borderColor: "#ccc",
                                    borderWidth: 1

                                },
                                {
                                    datalabels: {
                                        color: 'black',
                                        font: {
                                            weight: 'bold'
                                        }
                                    },
                                    label: "2ndEvaluation",
                                    data: SecondEvaluationData,
                                    order: SecondOrder,
                                   
                                    //backgroundColor: "#e8c3b9",
                                    backgroundColor: point2BackgroundColors,
                                    borderColor: "#ccc",
                                    borderWidth: 1
                                }
                            ]
                        },

                        options: {
                            tooltips: {
                                callbacks: {
                                    label: function (tooltipItem) {

                                        var label = tooltipItem.label;
                                        var score = tooltipItem.yLabel;
                                        return label, score + '%';
                                    }

                                },
                                filter: function (tooltipItem, data) {
                                    var value = tooltipItem.value;
                                    if (value == 50.5348) {
                                        return false;
                                    } else {
                                        return true;
                                    }
                                }

                            },


                            onClick: function (c, data) {
                                debugger
                                e = data[0];

                                var name = this.data.labels[e._index];
                                var y_value = this.data.datasets[0].data[e._index];
                                var id = this.data.datasets[0].order[e._index];
                                if (y_value == 50.5348) {
                                    Pending(name, EmployeeId);
                                }
                                else {
                                    Evaluation(name, EmployeeId);
                                }


                            },


                            responsive: true,
                            title: { display: true, text: 'Evaluation Graph For Current Period' },
                            legend: { position: 'top' },
                            scales: {

                                xAxes: [{ gridLines: { display: true }, display: true, scaleLabel: { display: true, labelString: 'Evaluation Dates' }, barPercentage: 1.0, categoryPercentage: 0.6 }],
                                yAxes: [{ gridLines: { display: true }, display: true, scaleLabel: { display: true, labelString: 'Score in ( % )' }, ticks: { beginAtZero: true } }]
                            },
                            plugins: {
                                datalabels: {

                                    formatter: function (value, context) {

                                        if (value == 50.5348) {

                                            return "pending"
                                        }
                                        else {
                                            return context.dataset.label;
                                        }

                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });


                    for (i = 0; i < myNewMonthChart.data.datasets[0].data.length; i++) {
                        if (myNewMonthChart.data.datasets[0].data[i] == 50.5348) {
                            pointBackgroundColors.push("#e7e7e7");


                        } else {

                            pointBackgroundColors.push("#00c0ef");
                        }
                    }
                    for (i = 0; i < myNewMonthChart.data.datasets[1].data.length; i++) {
                        if (myNewMonthChart.data.datasets[1].data[i] == 50.5348) {
                            point2BackgroundColors.push("#e7e7e7");


                        } else {

                            point2BackgroundColors.push("#dd4b39");
                        }
                    }
                    myNewMonthChart.update();

                }
                else {
                    $("#myChart").remove();
                    $('#lblnodata').css('display', 'block');
                    $('#lblnodata').html('<h3>No Data For Selected Periods</h3>');
                }
            }
```